# How can i locate the php that generated a html element?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am literally pulling my hair off trying to corrent something on my site.

I currently use Wordpress as plataform and a specfic theme ,that i am gradually changing to fit my needs.

The thing is , there is a goddamned comment box that i can't get rid of,i used inspect element and it simple leaded me to nowhere, even the plugin " locate file" could not point out where is this line of code so i can remove it.

Seems to me that the element is generated by a php or a JS file,but this alone wans't enough to solve the issue.

I would be imensilly grateful if someone could tell me how to find that element.

Comment: There is no easy way to do it. you'd need to share the code so we could help or search the entire project for one string that you can identify the specific code.

Comment: I would recommend you searching the files themselves. If you're using linux, first find the comment box you're looking (we'll assume it has id `comment-box`). Then go to the root of your wordpress and type `grep comment-box * -R` hopefully it returns you the file where it's contained in.

Comment: And this is the reason why I don't use platforms. It may be harder to complete the full project by doing it on your own, but debugging is so much easier.

Comment: @A.Lau Seconded! [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and [Textpad](https://www.textpad.com/) both have excellent multi-file search. Notepad++ can even limit to files with a name matching a regular expression.

Comment: @A.Lau +1 : ) btw. comment-box might be generated dynamically so if you can't find it try searching for some other part of comment-box element. As for IDE's you might try php-storm, it has nice search as well.

Comment: Well i will try to use the the "ID=Reply-title" element using the the programs you guys told me.
Thanks for the help!